# How to prevent duplicate lines in a wordlist with python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I will receive many different words from a `for` loop. I need to identify if that word appeared before at loop, if not, each unique word must be saved into a txt file, if the word already appereared, then the logic must return to the `for` loop for the next word.

I will receive a lot of words, so, this logic needs to be light for RAM memory.

Comment: Have you used a set?

Comment: Turn your `list` of words into a `set` and you'll instantly deduplicate them.

Comment: @EricDuminil No... I don't think so. There is nothing being removed here. It seems like words are coming from a function call/generator.

Comment: @COLDSPEED: You're right. Shame on me, I didn't bother to read the "duplicate" completely. If you have a better match... I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). It will prevent duplicate entries.

If you already have a list of words:

```
world_list = [...]  # a list of words
output = set(word_list)
```

If you're reading from an input stream, like from a file:

```
output = set()
for line in f.readline():
    output.add(line)
```

You can then write your `set` to a text file, just like you would with a `list`.